# How to loop values of same column to same column value as an output?

Tags: data-management, ab-initio

How can I achieve a specific looping operation in `Ab Initio` where I need to take values from the same column and generate a new column with the paired values as output, as illustrated in the example below?

**Input:**

|  |
| --- |
| Delhi |
| Hyderabad |
| Pune |
| Mumbai |

**Desired Output:**

|  |  |
| --- | --- |
| Delhi | Hyderabad |
| Delhi | Pune |
| Delhi | Mumbai |
| Hyderabad | Pune |
| Hyderabad | Mumbai |
| Pune | Mumbai |

I'm looking for guidance on the procedure to achieve this in `Ab Initio`. Thanks in advance.